# IntelliJ IDE hover - offers nothing?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I've moved from eclipse to intellij (13.1.4)  .

However - when I'm hovering a word , it doesn't offer nothing :

Isn't intellij offers its own  tooltip , signature , something ???

I'm not talking about the documentation window where you can see by `ctrl+Q`

Currently - The only things I see is when I press `ctrl` + hover a word :

[image]

Or via `ctrl+Q` : (I know I can also set it show when hover)

[image]

**Question**

Is there any setting which I don't know about which shows a tooltip or some information when hovering?

Comment: What *kind* of information were you looking for?  If you hover over the same symbol in a debug context, you'll get different info.

Comment: @Makoto the signature at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA for almost a year, and I'm not aware of any popups when hovering (aside from the documentation which you already know).

Perhaps you're looking for the "Intention Actions" popup menu. The menu can be accessed by clicking the yellow bulb or by typing (Alt + Enter) when selecting something.

Comment: Compared to Eclipse it kinda sucks that you always need keyboard instead of getting menu of actions with mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

Go as per below, Select ***Show quick doc on Mouse move*** on editor section.

**File -- >Setting ---> Editor(IDE Setting) ---> Show quick doc on Mouse move**

Comment: I know that. I also mentioned it : http://i.stack.imgur.com/sLZfD.jpg - im looking for it's own (intellij) helper baloon and not the giant doc window.